# Why doesn't my angular-js jsonp request work when querying solr

Tags: javascript, angularjs, solr, jsonp

When I try to query my solr server using this code:

```
var url ="http://localhost:8080/solr/sdc/selectwt=json&callback=JSON_CALLBACK&q=opioid"
$http.jsonp(url ).success(function(res){
    console.log(res)
})
```

I get an error from my console:

```
select?wt=json&callback=angular.callbacks._0&q=opioid:formatted:1
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

I can see my response, it looks like this:

```
{"responseHeader":{"status":0,"QTime":0,"params":{"q":"opioid","callback":"angular.callbacks._0","wt":"json"}},"response":{"numFound":28,"start":0,"docs": ........
```

plus all the documents them-self. I've tried the code with a different URL from another users example and the code works. It looks like it isn't happy with the format of the Solr response, specifically the first `:`

I dont quite know if I Understand what jsonp is enough to debug this. Jsonp feels a little hacky already. Is it safe to use in a corporate environment?

Comment: The service doesn't appear to support jsonp. If it does, the response would be wrapped in with the callback function.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working when I implemented it myself... Not sure why the supplied version fails.

```
.factory( 'searchService', function ( $q ) {
    var search_service = {};

    search_service.search = function ( query ) {
        return $q(function(resolve, reject){
            var jsonpReq = document.createElement("script");

            /*Json callback, called from injected script tag*/
            loadResults = function (jsonResp) {
                resolve(jsonResp)
            };

            jsonpReq.src = 'http://localhost:8080/solr/sdc/select?wt=json&json.wrf=loadResults&q=' + query;
            jsonpReq.type = "text/javascript";
            document.body.appendChild(jsonpReq);
        })

    };

    return search_service;
} )
```

Note `$q` promisses requires you to use `.then()` instead of `.success()`

Answer (score 0):

append json.wrf=JSON_CALLBACK in your URL. this worked for me.

your url will be like

http://localhost:8080/solr/sdc/selectwt=json&json.wrf=JSON_CALLBACK&q=opioid

try it.

hope it will be helpfull.